# Lighting errors

Tags: modeling, topology, lighting

Ok, so my question may have an obvious solution that I am not seeing since I am quite new to blender.

I was working on a logo project and when I came out of orthographic view the lighting was extremely weird.

It probably some setting I accidentally clicked. Or the matcap I have on.

I am using blender version 2.79
Attached are photos of the problem.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going into edit mode then selecting all and doing CTRL - N, it should reset the normal, not 100% sure if that's the problem but worth a try.